# Google Form AppScript - Item choices disappear when viewing, however it's showing in editing view?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I created an add-on to import questions & choices as multiple choice items in Forms.

The questions, answers & correct answer were imported perfectly and shows as expected in editing view, however when previewing the form/quiz, some questions have choices missing.

Any ideas?

```
function createMCQ(k) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.setIsQuiz(true)
  .setShuffleQuestions(true)
  .setAllowResponseEdits(false)
  .setLimitOneResponsePerUser(false)
  .setCollectEmail(true)
  .setShowLinkToRespondAgain(false);
  
  
  for (var i = 0, len = k.length; i < len; i++) {
    var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
    item.setTitle(k[i].question)
    .setPoints('1')
    .setRequired(true)
    .setChoices([
    item.createChoice(String(k[i].a), Boolean(k[i].answer =='A')),
    item.createChoice(String(k[i].b), Boolean(k[i].answer =='B')),
    item.createChoice(String(k[i].c), Boolean(k[i].answer =='C')),
    item.createChoice(String(k[i].d), Boolean(k[i].answer =='D')),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Where it's imported from object like so;

```
"questions": [
    {
      "course": "GCSE AQA Biology",
      "question": "State the equation that links magnification, image size and actual size.",
      "a": "Actual Size = Image Size / Magnification",
      "b": "Actual Size = Magnification / Image Size",
      "c": "Actual Size = Resolution / Magnification",
      "d": "Resolution = Image Size / Magnification",
      "topic": "Cells",
      "answer": "A",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "course": "GCSE AQA Biology",
      "question": "Which type of microscope has higher magnification and resolving power?",
      "a": "Light Microscopes",
      "b": "Magnifying Glass",
      "c": "Super Microscope",
      "d": "Electron microscopes",
      "topic": "Cells",
      "answer": "D",
      "id": 3
    }
]
```

Items imported perfectly as shown when editing:

[image: Items imported perfectly as shown when editing]

However, when previewing form, the choices for some of them missing:

[image: When previewing form, choices missing!]

This is very random i.e. not isolated to certain questions.

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I managed to fix (?) this;

When adding the multiple choice item, I added the choices first before any other properties:

```
k.map(e => {
    var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
    item.setTitle(e.question)
    .setChoices([
    item.createChoice(String(e.a), Boolean(e.answer =='A')),
    item.createChoice(String(e.b), Boolean(e.answer =='B')),
    item.createChoice(String(e.c), Boolean(e.answer =='C')),
    item.createChoice(String(e.d), Boolean(e.answer =='D')),
    ])
    .setPoints('1')
    .setRequired(true);
})
```

Using map instead of for doesn't have to do with anything tho.

I did a few tests, and it looks like the answer choices no longer disappear. Fingers crossed! Might be a Google's bug?

Comment: I have the same problem, I've created the form with an Apps Sprits import script, the choices show as expected in editing view, but when previewing the form/quiz, some questions have choices missing. Does anyone has found a solution for this behaviour?

Comment: From my testing, the last things you do can still be left un-updated. For instance, after setChoices(...), I did setPoint(1) and then setRequired(true). This way, all my choices were intact (great!). But then some questions have points of 0 and required of false. As a work around, I had to do a second run-through on all items to set points and required again. But at least I don't have to re-check the choices.